# Github for Windows with Gitlab community edition

Tags: gitlab, github-for-windows

Having searched here on Stack Overflow and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639815/does-github-for-windows-work-with-gitlab), I now understand that Github for Windows will work with Gitlab.

I'm using the Community edition of Gitlab on a local server and I can't get it to work, so just to expand upon the question I've linked above, can anyone confirm if it will work with the community edition of Gitlab?

I've tried to connect with my email and password, with the URL set to the base URL of the installation (`https://git.example.com/`), am I perhaps just using the wrong URL for this? I'm finding documentation for Github for Windows is somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What worked for me was loading up and logging into GitLab in your browser. Navigating to the repository you want, highlighting and drag/drop the https url for your repo into the GitHub for Windows app. It will clone locally, and ask you to login.

Comment: This worked for me! I was able to create an empty project, follow your instructions, then put my files into it. Thanks!