# On the brink of understanding version control with Git ... still confused by a couple things

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, github-for-windows

I've researched nearly every (seemingly) available resource on how Git works and how to use Git for version control.

I'm on the brink of understanding this ... pull requests, committs, repos, it makes sense ... except for one aspect (please correct me if I'm wrong) ...

Say right now I have a local folder with site files for a live site being hosted on my local server.  I downloaded Git, I downloaded GitHub desktop client, and I have a GitLab account because I'd like a private repo for the current project I'm working on, for free ...

Question 1: say the file path of my site folder is "C:\site" ... how do I connect / turn this into a private repo on GitLab? ...

Question 2: Once connected to GitLab, how do I then connect this to the GitHub desktop client? ...

Question 3: I've researched tons of threads, and the fact that I'm still questioning this either shows that people aren't communicating this as effectively and efficiently as they could, or I'm not understanding something, or both ... How does live editing work? When I edit the files locally, do only I see an edited version of the site from my local folder in my browser until I commit the changes to the server? Example: say I'm editing index.php, adding a form. Do only I see the changes I'm making while everyone else sees a formless index.php page, until I commit the changes? If so, how do I separated the live folder from the git folder? Is it automatic? Any help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:**
If you are just starting out, it will be easier to create a repository in Gitlab and clone this using a git tool (either console/bash or a GUI tool).
I've never used a GUI tool for Git, but as far as my research has shown, the GitHub client WILL work with a Gitlab repository, but you might have to clone the repository first, using another tool. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639815/does-github-for-windows-work-with-gitlab) for more info.

**Question 2:**
I am not entirely sure about this, as I've never used the client. But I would assume there is some sort of "Open/Add folder" option in the interface. A folder becomes a Git repository when there's a `.git` folder inside.

**Question 3:**
The remote repository and local repository are not synchronized. Whatever you do in your local repository, whether that be make code changes, make commits, delete history, or whatever else, it'll only be affecting your local repository. In order to make the changes "live" on the remote repository, you will have to `push` the changes to the remote repository, which will basically just "upload" your commits to the remote repository.

I hope this helps clarify git a bit.

Comment: I'll be testing this in the morning and responding ... thank you for your feedback ...

Answer (score 2):

1. Let's assume `C:\\site\` is a folder that contains your site on your local machine that currently isn't a Git repo.
   The first thing you do is `git init` to initialise a Git repo in your folder.
   Then `add` and `commit` your current code to create an initial commit in your Git history.
   Then you can add a link to an ***empty*** remote repository location (in your case, a GitLab URL) using `git remote add origin <remote_repo_URL>`.
   Then you can `push` the code from your *local* repo, to your *remote* repo.
   Edit: The `origin` part of this command will be the reference name you will use for the remote repository. Industry/Git standard is `origin` though you can name it anything.
2. You can follow [this guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639815/does-github-for-windows-work-with-gitlab) or [this guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548236/can-we-use-the-github-mac-app-with-gitlab), to connect your GitHub client to GitLab/Your GitLab repository.
3. Git isn't a live-editing tool. It's just a VCS. Any changes that you make *locally* (i.e. on your machine), are only view-able by you because they are ***local*** changes.
   If you want other people to view your changes on their respective *local* machines, you'll need to `commit` and `push` your changes to a *remote* repo that you can both access; At which point, the other person(s) can do a `git pull` to `fetch` and `merge` your changes into their code.
   Live editing does not exist in Git, if you want to do Live Editing, you'll need to use a Live Editing tool/system however, none AFAIK have support for Git.

Hope that helps clear up some stuff, I can always add/edit to this if your still confused about specifics.

Comment: I'll be testing this in the morning and responding ... thank you for your feedback ...

Comment: Okay ... I'm at the git remote add <remote_repo_url> step ... I pressed enter and get a "usage" prompt with different options ... the GitLab account online doesn't show any changes yet ...

Comment: Sorry, I've mistyped the `git remote add` command. I'll fix it.

Comment: GitLab says "You won't be able to pull or push project code via SSH until you add an SSH key to your profile" and no changes showed yet on GitLab account online ...

Comment: If you're trying to connect to GitLab via SSH rather than HTTP or HTTPS, you'll need to look into that. [The GitLab docs would be a good place to start](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html)